# Forcing minimum required width for float

Tags: html, css, css-float

As simple as it gets:

Is there any way to clear a floating **div**, without stripping it of its capacity to take only as much width as it needs?

Comment: clear:both, left or right. ? can you clarify ?

Comment: Do you mean `display: inline;`? ;)

Comment: Well, i have `div`s in a container, wanting them to each take one full block, but i also want them to use up only their minimum required width, which `float:left` gives me, but then they - of course - float next to each other, which i don't want :)

Comment: Use `clear: both` like GCyrillus said. On your divs.

Comment: Clearing is not what i am looking for, otherwise i could skip using floats altogether, given this situation.

Comment: Could you show graphically or with and example what do you mean?